# A deep hole in Stack Exchange moderation philosophy: dealing with the human element

Tags: discussion, moderation

Over the past year, I've learned a lot as a moderator. Recent events on other sites, SE and not, stick out sharply in my mind, reminiscent of the mistakes I've made and problems that have arisen in helping a beta community grow. I have a lot of thoughts on this, but one sticks out: developing a strong, self-moderating, friendly, welcoming community is hard, and I've made a lot of errors in doing so.

I don't think it had to be this way -- or at least quite this error-ridden.

In thinking, I've found that the tools designed to help moderators understand their role in assisting community growth are... lacking. That's not to say the onus isn't on me, but rather that a lot of growing pains could have been avoided through better tools and advice.

---

A lot of this is going to be based on impressions and observations - most of which will have to stay unlinked - so I apologize in advance for the lack of references. I'll try to keep the anecdote to a minimum, but some will be necessary to clarify my thought process.

I became a moderator not too long before SE started releasing help info for mods. It wasn't too long before we got some written content, but most of it is on function rather than philosophy.

So new mods are, in a lot of ways, flying blind on philosophy. In some ways, I can see why this might help: if you have a ton of responsibility and control, but don't know exactly what to do with it, you're probably going to be pretty careful when touching things.

Still, mods are told that we're human exception handlers; that we're the garbagemen of the site; that we're there to help and clarify on meta. All these things are true, but it's critically lacking: **mods are *also* there to help the community learn to self-moderate, and to foster a friendly and helpful environment.** In short:

- growing a community of knowledgeable contributors - even on graduated sites
- encouraging self-moderation
- encouraging a friendly and sane environment
- fostering good meta discussions

None of these things are really mentioned, and no advice is given on these points, and it's only after several months of deliberation that I've seen *this* is what my moderation has been lacking.

I've been far too focused on *technical* success, and far too little on *human* success.

---

Ultimately, **what I'm asking for is a re-evaluation, not just by CMs, but also moderators and users, of what it means to be a good moderator.** Right now, moderation on Stack Exchange is a very technical process, and this isn't surprising given its origin. But I don't think it should be - moderating is inherently a human process, and the advice and information moderators need should reflect that.

I realize what I'm asking is difficult; describing how to use a *system* is easy, while describing how to help *people* is hard. Still, I think it's been overlooked, and I think we could do a better job of it overall.

Comment: I'm not sure you're asking for a reevaluation. You seem to have done this already and suggested a gap in the current help available. Fair enough - you think mods should be leaders as well as garbage wo/men. Teaching someone to be a leader is a lengthy process, partly because a lot of it is experience and partly because it will normally require the individual modifying their own behaviour.

Comment: @ben Yeah, I get that. Didacticism isn't necessarily what I'm going for, though. A lot of it is changing the answer to the question, "what does an SE mod do?", which is more about what people think than what happens. Still, more help resources would be nice.

Comment: Wow this is a masterpiece! I'd really like to link to this next time someone asks me what the `<censored>` a mod is supposed to do in an SE community.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani aren't you over exaggerating or am I missing the  pun?

Comment: Hm @Rene I think it was mainly because I came back here after reading a *downvote whine* somewhere else; still doesn't change the fact that it's a great post. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm surprised that you feel that way; I've been a moderator for longer, but the guidance I've gotten on moderatorship hasn't changed all that much. The guidance includes the janitor bit, but it also includes the human element and guidance bits. I've always felt that at least on small to medium sites (it's different at the scale of Stack Overflow), the technical side was only a small part of moderation. And that's coming from a scientist turned engineer, a background that's stereotypically driven to underestimate the human element.

Let me quote from [the blog post “A Theory of Moderation”](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) (formerly hosted at https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), which is linked in moderator nomination threads on beta sites, on the election nomination page for graduate sites, and in the email you receive from Stack Exchange when you're offered a beta moderator position¹.

> So in summary, if you are a community moderator on a Stack Exchange
> site, here's what to expect:
>
> 1. As a moderator, your actions now represent the community, so you will
>    be held to a higher standard of behavior. You are an ambassador of
>    trust, with the same sorts of rights that the official development
>    team and community coordinators have.
> 2. Your goal is to guide the community with gentle -- but firm --
>    intervention. Respect your fellow community members at all times;
>    demonstrate fairness and impartiality in your actions.
> 3. Whenever possible, try to leave frequent comments on posts where
>    you've taken (or considered taking) a moderator action, explaining the
>    reasoning. This is important so that community members can learn the
>    norms of the community and the moderation policies.
> 4. Keep the site reasonably on topic by closing, migrating, or removing
>    blatantly off-topic questions.
> 5. Regularly check for flagged posts, and decide if further action is
>    warranted.
> 6. In the case of serious disputes, communicate directly with users via
>    email to help mediate and resolve those disputes.

The wording has changed a bit from [the original](https://web.archive.org/web/20090520212955/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). In particular point #3 about leaving comments was added in December 2010. Comparing with your points:

- “growing a community of knowledgeable contributors - even on graduated sites” — depending on what you mean by “grow”, this may or may not be covered. If you mean grow as in recruit participants, point 1 reminds you that you official status as a moderator makes you an ambassador — but if you meant that moderators are supposed to go out and evangelize, then no, that's neither required of nor restricted to moderators. If you mean grow as in protect and help the community as it grows, that's definitely covered by points 2 and 6. If you mean grow as in, yourself, be a knowledgeable contributor, that's expected, again, from point 2, as well as from “guide by example” which comes up elsewhere, but moderators are not expected to bear more than their share of content generation; I'll have more on that topic further below.
- “encouraging self-moderation” — hence point 3. I think point 2 could be clarified that guidance includes encouragements to self-moderation (like telling users to vote to close rather than merely comment to complain about a question they think doesn't belong on the site).
- “encouraging a friendly and sane environment” — points 1, 2 and 6.
- “fostering good meta discussions” — this one should be added to point 3.

So I do see a few points that should be updated in this post:

- Clarify #2 as discussed above.
- Mention meta in #3.
- Remove the mention of email in #6 since moderators are strongly discouraged from using email — they're supposed to use chat and, for serious private issues, moderator messages.

In any case, if you aren't getting out of it that a moderator's role is primarily the human element, the guidance definitely needs to emphasize that more.

My own take on what being a moderator entails would be three points.

- You get extra tools, such as flag handling. Just like users with the vote to close privilege should exercise that privilege to keep the site running, you need to use these tools to keep the site running.
- You are the ultimate arbiter of disputes, unless they rise above your level to the site administrators. While anyone can act as a mediator, that diamond gives you more weight.
- Every community has charismatic leaders, people whom at least part of the community regards as people who act in the interests of the community, and trust to resolve issues in a satisfactory manner. You don't need to be a moderator to be a charismatic leader, but a good moderator should be one of the charismatic leaders.

Now, **how** to do all of these human element things… That's missing from all the guidance. Writing the documentation of how flags work is easier than writing the documentation on how humans work. While some of it can be taught, a lot has to come from experience. That's why we have Q&A sites (your site's and the main meta — and also, for issues that are not really specific to Stack Exchange there is now [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/)) and chat rooms where moderators can find guidance.

---

Now, as promised, some thoughts on “growing a community of knowledgeable contributors” and guiding by example. You don't need to be a moderator to guide by example. The diamond next to your name may lead to your words having more credence, but it is not a necessity by any means.

Upvoting good posts and downvoting bad ones, commenting to explain why you made an edit or voted to close or reopen a question when the reason is not obvious, suggesting that people take an issue to chat and meta, participating in meta discussions are all things that need to happen in a functional community. Moderators have no monopoly on these things and no technical advantage over a user with sufficient reputation. Moderators have an advantage when settling an issue, because they can edit/close/reopen/delete/… immediately. But anybody except for very new users can initiate discussions. As a moderator, you should do it, but that's only because *as a user who wants the site to succeed*, you should do it.

Guiding the community in other ways is something that non-moderators can do too. For example, [A guide to moderating crypto.stackexchange yourself - close voting](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129/a-guide-to-moderating-crypto-stackexchange-yourself-close-voting) was initially written by a moderator — but it's been copied to other meta sites, not always by moderators. As a moderator, you should look for issues like this that your community doesn't deal with satisfactorily (another example is the excessive commenting [mentioned by enderland on Workplace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260045)). But as a non-moderator who wants the site to succeed, you should also look for such issues and you can make similar posts.

One way I've been influential on several Stack Exchange sites is by writing detailed answers that not only provide a fish, but also explain what kind of bait I used, discuss what kind of currents that fish is to be found in, and warn of the environmental consequences of overfishing. I don't do that only because writing long texts is easier than summarizing them, or because I like pontificating; I do it because that's the kind of answers I want to read, and I'm setting an example. I've heard from several [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) contributors that my answers inspired them, and I consider that my biggest success. Being a moderator would have been irrelevant for that, even mildly distracting.

¹  <sub>I presume that you're reminded if you get elected too. I don't know for sure when I was elected, I was already a beta moderator, so I didn't *become* a moderator at that point, and I didn't receive an email.</sub>

Comment: I've been thinking about this over the past day and a half. It definitely is changing the way I think about moderation, and I'm going to need to re-evaluate what becoming a mod looks like again.

Answer (score 26):

Disclaimer: this applies to smaller sites. It will not apply in the same way to huge sites such as StackOverflow/etc. Those sites are large enough that individuals have a much, much lower ability to influence a site community and culture.

---

tl;dr: everything you do as a moderator is actually a people/human issue, and not a technical issue.

> I've been far too focused on technical success, and far too little on human success.

I guess this is the part I am confused about as my experience doesn't match at all. I have never once thought about this problem, because every issue on a site that might be a technical issue actually *is* a people issue. If anything becoming a moderator allows you to be *better* at focusing on the human side than the technical site (flags, etc) since everything you do relates to the people/community.

For example:

- If you have a problem user who likes to say offensive things, that's not just a technical "delete comment" issue. It is a culture and people issue - does a site condone this? Do comments like that get flagged and is there information being directed towards those users? Do you need a post like [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322)?
- Workplace suffers from comment mania. We have multiple threads on meta, and are one of the [top ten most prolific commenting sites](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2753/2322). This is again not a "delete comments, move on" issue because the culture of commenting is a *people issue* - not a technical issue.
- Moderators can lead by example and encourage users to edit/flag/etc in a way that normal users cannot (well, technically anyone can, but that little ♦ makes a bigger impact). This is a huge responsibility and has a lot of ability to influence site culture, again influencing people, not just technical issues.
- Everytime you delete anything you have taken content someone wrote away. That's bound to cause emotional reactions in some way!

> Right now, moderation on Stack Exchange is a very technical process, and this isn't surprising given its origin.

I suggest that there may be a few deeper issues here.

1. This suggests a problem with quality or site scope. A site *needs* a reasonably clear and meaningful scope understood by the community. Early sites have a lot of issues with this, since... there is no defined scope! Moderators can be critical in guiding this process (not defining it themselves). A site without a community understanding for the scope means that a moderator will be whacking all off-topic questions.
2. Question quality is the #1 item of importance, followed closely by #2 of answer quality. As a moderator you have huge ability to influence this. As a site matures, you need to involve the community more via meta/etc. Programmers is doing a community cleanup of old, now offtopic questions now - this is led by moderators. **
3. Users don't flag or do any community moderation. If you, moderator(s), are the only folks doing editing/closing/deleting, then that's a community issue again. Your [role as a moderator](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) is supposed to be leading by example, being patient and fair, and ultimately helping set the pace for a site -- not being the only people doing it.

Also, I would suggest taking time to answer/ask questions. I actively participate in Workplace and it's community and answer [many questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/2322/enderland?tab=answers). This not only keeps me interested in the community aspect but also helps other people on the site see me as a person and not a flag handling monster.

I could keep writing here at length about how moderator actions are completely tied to the community part of a site but it's already long enough.

---

**As an aside, I ran on the platform of [unilaterally closing questions](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2863/2322) as my first response to the election questionnaire. However, over time, the Workplace community has done too damn well at voting to close those questions before I even see them, so I nearly never get to do this!

Comment: This makes sense for the most part. I wonder if what needs reconsidering isn't the philosophy but the advice SE gives to new moderators. This makes me question whether what I'm saying is actually the true philosophy, but the advice definitely isn't there for new mods. (Even the page you link focuses on the mechanics rather than the purpose.)

Comment: [This blog post about pro-tem moderators](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) has been excerpted and linked on the "call for nomination" posts I've seen on the last several betas I've participated in.  Is that the kind of thing you're looking for @Emrakul?

Comment: @Monica Truthfully, my tangible ideal is a page on /help/mods discussing the point of moderators and what we're here for, but creating one would need to start with a discussion on what it means to be a moderator.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  Is the information in that blog post (and "a theory of moderation") the sort of thing you'd like to see linked in /help/mods?

Comment: @Monica I'm going to have to follow up later, sorry -- getting sidetracked by shenanigans.

Comment: Overall I thought most of what you touched on was easier for new mods to handle. Aside from one exceptionally important aspect, scope. Your point #2 squarely highlights the problem that is being described by the OP in my opinion. I think that the point made exists especially on smaller exchanges and at times a mod without proper interpretation of what is on topic can accidentally crush the willingness of users to post new questions and can also remove valuable content. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the issue of having a well defined scope for an exchange, especially one in beta?

Comment: regarding that cleanup at Programmers you mentioned - I don't closely follow it, but per my observations it would be more accurate to say that leading these efforts is shared between moderators and active regulars. At the surface, it may even appear that mod involvement in there is quite limited (to find out that it ain't so, one needs to have an access to [meta-tag:10K-tools] page over there and regularly check it)